# How to insert and increment a value in one field based on field from same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table and task `field id = web_actividade.TicketID`. I need to insert into this table values from other table and increment the `DayWork` field based on last `MAX(DayWork)` related to the field id `TicketID`. So if I have `TicketID` 12 with `MAX(DayWork)=2` the code must insert 3 into `DayWork` field.

```sql
INSERT INTO web_actividade(Name,TicketID,tipo_actividade,client,Description,CPost,obs,DayWork)
SELECT t1.Resp,t1.NR_Obra,t1.tipo,t1.client,t1.Description,t1.CPost,'NEW DAY',DiaWork + 1
FROM nr_obra t1
INNER JOIN web_actividade t2
ON t1.NR_Obra=t2.TicketID
WHERE t1.NR_Obra=t2.TicketID AND t2.ClosedTicket="NO";
```

The code sintaxe is ok and runs but the DayWork does not increments.

EDITED:
I change `t2.DiaWork=(t2.DiaWork)+1` to `DiaWork + 1`. Now increments but not in the right way...As shown on image. Started with `DiaWork = 1` after run the code only 3 times. The rigth result must be ID 976=2, 977=3, 978=4 and so on, image: [Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TqiC.png)

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you're trying to do. Could you elaborate? From the part ```t2.DiaWork=(t2.DiaWork)+1``` it seems like you want to update the field ```DiaWork``` in table ```web_actividade```, but it is not possible to update an entry within a ```SELECT``` query. Do you perhaps want to work with a variable that increments on each execution of the insert statement?

Comment: I have edited and change only to `DiaWork + 1`. Now it increments but not in the right way as I posted on edited. Thank you Ott.

Comment: Could you perhaps work with an ```AUTO-INCREMENT``` column? I'll be honest, I still don't understand what the requirements for this increment are, specifically how it relates to the seemingly unconnected column ```TicketID```. Generally counting with MySQL can be tricky. The three major ways are auto-increments, generator views or variables that are incremented on each execution (but can't handle ```INSERT INTO X (...) SELECT (...) FROM Y``` if more than one row is selected.

Comment: The relation with `TicketID`... counts the worked days of a ticket. The all ideia is to find `TicketID` with `t2.ClosedTicket = 'NO'` copy (insert) the data from the other table and increment the `DayWork + 1`. I know this maybe tricky specially when we deal with more than one `TicketID ` (Oops! it already is). I initially start with `SELECT TicketID, MAX(DiaWork) FROM web_actividade` and than try and include it into the above code. But it seems that `WHERE t1.NR_Obra=t2.TicketID AND t2.ClosedTicket="NO" AND (SELECT MAX(t2.DiaWork) FROM web_actividade);` makes no difference at all...